# Autoplay видео с ютуба

Tags: wordpress, youtube

Всем привет!
У меня есть проект на Wordpress. Нужно сделать что бы плейлист из ютуба начинал работать после загрузки страницы.

Видео добавлено через iframe, ниже будет код

`<iframe width="1100" height="610" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DNbpRYdbTEs?list=PLOP7BtywblPOHW0FwYjIqX5N51OE8_rng" title="Триставісім - Дислокація (official video)" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Если я добавляю в ссылку  `?autoplay=1` , выдает ошибку, что такого видео не существует.

Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: а так добавить : &autoplay=1
?

Comment: В элементоре работает, а на сайте не запускается. 
Вот ссылка на страницу - https://www.grailyst.com/веселий-плейлист/